# GCP Custom Role Doesn't work for equivalent permissions required

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

'gcloud compute instance import' command, demand 5 roles to run properly:

1. Compute Admin
2. Service Account Token Creator
3. Service Account User
4. Compute Storage Admin
5. Storage Object Viewer

Creating custom role with collection of permissions from these roles, doesn't satisfy the demand for these roles.

I created a custom role contained the permissions of 5 predefined roles, which required to create VM from OVA file.
After attaching the role to service accounts, the gcloud shell keep asking to grant the predefined roles to those service accounts.

It's build in a way that expects to see the names of this particular roles? the permissions itself doesn't enough?

Comment: You can create a custom IAM role with permissions. However, if existing IAM roles exist, then you should them instead of creating your own custom role. Permissions change, and services change. Use Google-managed IAM roles so that changes are managed by Google instead of you finding out something no longer works. If you still want to create a custom role, then edit your question and show exactly what you are doing. I can only guess with the details presented so far.

Comment: When you have a custom role contains 5 roles permissions, you gain 2 things. First, it's suites certain job you want to do sometimes that requires these 5 roles. than you can address this specification with this particular role.
Second, You add and remove only 1 role every time you need, instead of 5.

Comment: 1) Some of the IAM roles you list can be merged as they are subsets of others (Token Creator / Token User) (Storage Admin / Storage Viewer). Now you are only talking about three roles. 2) Your argument that adding and removing 1 role is better than 5 is not a good argument. Inconvenience when configuring security is never a good argument. Sacrificing managed security (Google-defined roles) so that you can manually manage potentially hundreds of permissions is a very poor tradeoff. Edit your post with sufficient details so that an answer can be generated.